# Why does Internet Explorer refresh when I click "always allow popups"?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet-explorer, popups

Why does Internet Explorer always refresh the page when I click "always allow popups"?

When Internet Explorer blocks a popup from a particular website, it asks me if I'd like to temporarily allow popups, or always allow them from this site.

It always refreshes itself no matter which one I click.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I prevent this from happening?

You can't. And even if you could, you shouldn't.

Once the popup got blocked, it got blocked. The whole page has to be reloaded to make sure that the site will behave properly.

Examples:

1. The URL of the popup is linked to some variable. This variable might have changed.
2. Part of the code only gets executed if the popup could be opened.

EDIT: If a link opens the popup, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking the link should open the popup without needing to refresh the page.

Comment: The popup is to a link.  I click on a link, and a window pops up.  No variable, no code.  You're saying that it's impossible to turn that  "feature off"?

Comment: If it is a link that opens the popup, pressing `Ctrl` while clicking the link should open the popup without refreshing the page.

Comment: "The whole page has to be reloaded to make sure that the site will behave properly." What a positively massive assumption by the IE developers. This is a holdover from a time before JavaScript enabled sites. It's actually very easy for this to be detected and handled by the script opening the popup.

There's a reason Chrome and FF don't do this.